# colorbar changes the size of subplot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I use the following code to generate side-by-size images and I need to add colorbar only to the second image in the row. I use the following code for it

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

def plotting(x):
    gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
    gs1.update(wspace=0.005, hspace=0.005)
    plt.subplot(gs1[0])
    plt.imshow(x)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title('dog')
    ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[1])
    imc = plt.imshow(x, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title('dog')
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    plt.colorbar(imc, cax=cax)
    plt.tight_layout() 
    plt.show()
```

However it comes out the size of side-by-side images are not equal. I wonder how I could fix this issue?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ImageGrid](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#imagegrid), which was created exactly for this purpose:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

x = np.random.random(size=(10,10))


fig = plt.figure()
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,
                nrows_ncols = (1,2),
                axes_pad = 0.05,
                cbar_location = "right",
                cbar_mode="single",
                cbar_size="5%",
                cbar_pad=0.05
                )

grid[0].imshow(x)
grid[0].axis('off')
grid[0].set_title('dog')

imc = grid[1].imshow(x, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
grid[1].axis('off')
grid[1].set_title('dog')

plt.colorbar(imc, cax=grid.cbar_axes[0])
```

[image]