# Adjust size of 2 contour maps to height of color bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

The topic is not new but up till now all the examples i saw are used for random data and it somehow works with `ax.img`. However, i couldnt manage to make my code work. I have tried this solution with `ImageGrid` but i'm not sure how to defined my `grid[0]` and `grid[1]` ([colorbar changes the size of subplot in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428817/colorbar-changes-the-size-of-subplot-in-python)). I thought it supposed to be my first and second contour plot but it is not ... Below is a snippet of it.

```
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, aspect='equal')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, aspect='equal')
ax1.contourf(X,Y,z1,100,cmap='RdGy') #100 equally spaced intervals within the data range
axs=ax2.contourf(X,Y,z1_90,100,cmap='RdGy')

ax2.set_yticklabels([])
ax1.set_ylabel('Bond length $H_{2}$-$H_{3}$ ($\AA$)')
fig.text(0.5, 0.135, 'Bond length $H_{2}$-$H_{1}$ ($\AA$)', ha='center')
cbar=plt.colorbar(axs,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,label='E(Hartree)')
plt.tight_layout()
```

It would be great if you can give me hints how to solve the problem instead of pasting links because I have already googled a lot. As said above, the main problem here is that i have a `contourf` plot and not some random data ...
[image]

Comment: Another possibility: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42397467/8881141

Comment: Also see the second example in [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_colorbar_with_inset_locator.html) about how inset axes can be used to place a colorbar without "stealing" space from the subplot.